# Как добится временного игнорирования коллизии с конкретным обьектом?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

При столкновении персонажа с врагом персонаж на n секунд должен получить способность проходить сквозь врагов с тегом `Enemy`, но при этом он все так же должен быть способен ходить, прыгать и тд.

Была идея прикрепить на врага второй `BoxCollider2D` на уровне ног c минимальной высотой, и при столкновении с персонажем активировать его, а первый `BoxCollider2D` выключать, но мне кажется, что это косячный способ и можно сделать это правильнее и  проще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
         Physics.IgnoreCollision(collision.collider, collider);
    }
}
```

думаю, с задержкой сам разберешся :)